# javascript date time formatting to build a string

Tags: javascript, string, date

needs to be DateString = 20220831142259

Hi I need some help with building a javascript date string using the current date
do i need to use .toString on the dateparts to convert the int back? The date format is yyyymmddhhmmss

if the date parts are less than 9 then I want to concatenate a "0" to the string.

````
//getting the date parts of today 
var year = today().getFullYear().toString();
var month = (today().getMonth() + 1).toString();
var day =  today().getDate().toString()
var hours = today().getHours().toString();
var minutes = today().getMinutes().toString();
var seconds = today().getSeconds().toString();


//if the datepart is less than 9 then add a 0 to the beginning
if (int(month) <= "9") {
    int(month) = "0" + int(month);
}
if (int(day) <= "9") {
    int(day) = "0" + int(day);
}

if (int(hours) <= "9") {
    int(hours) = "0" + int(hours);
}

if (int(minutes) <= "9") {
    int(minutes) = "0" + int(minutes);
}

if (int(seconds) <= "9") {
    int(seconds) = "0" + int(seconds);
}

hours = 14
day = 31
minutes = 22
seconds = 59
month = 8

//build full date
DateString = 2022831142259```
````

Comment: What's the question?  `int(month) = "0" + int(month);` doesn't make much sense, if you want a string then left side should be a string and not an int.  You create tehm as strings, then in the 2nd part you assign numbers.

Comment: Have a look at my answer below, hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You just have a few issues when trying to work with strings versus numbers to perform the logic you want.

See below for a solution, results in the desired output of the string `20220831142259`. Explanation is given below the solution as well.

### Solution

```
const today = new Date();

// if you want to use the current date...
var year = today.getFullYear();
var month = today.getMonth() + 1;
var day = today.getDay();
var hours = today.getHours();
var minutes = today.getMinutes();
var seconds = today.getSeconds();

// if you want to use sample data...
year = 2022;
hours = 14;
day = 31;
minutes = 22;
seconds = 59;
month = 8;

// format our date parts and convert to strings
year = year.toString();
// if less than or equal to 9, then add a 0 to the beginning...
month = month <= 9 ? "0" + month : month.toString();
day = day <= 9 ? "0" + day : day.toString();
hours = hours <= 9 ? "0" + hours : hours.toString();
minutes = minutes <= 9 ? "0" + minutes : minutes.toString();
seconds = seconds <= 9 ? "0" + seconds : seconds.toString();

console.log(year + month + day + hours + minutes + seconds);
// results in "20220831142259"
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/manipulate-date-vals-format-string-d18xzr

### Explanation

When prefixing numbers 9 and under with a "0", we can simply append the number to the string `"0"` and the result will be of type `string`. This means the result of `getMonth()` (or a number from the sample data) is sufficient for our needs.

We also know we need to work with numbers when doing the conditional logic required for the date parts with numbers 9 or less, so there's no reason to turn the month into a string then back to an integer.

For each date part that requires the rule for numbers 9 or less, we check whether or not number is 9 or less.

If it is, we append the value to "0" as explained above.

If not, we simply convert the value to a string.

This gives us correctly formatted strings for all date parts.

Then, we simply concatenate all the date parts to get the final result.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use **if** statements to assign values like leading zeros, I like to use conditional assignments. Aside from that, you can avoid creating a lot of unneeded variables by just creating 1 date object and then extracting the parts that you need into 1 value.

Here, I have a function that creates a date object based on a date passed in (I am passing the current timestamp in via `Date.now()`, but you can pass in a date string too if needed). Then it returns the date string in the format you requested using `template literals`. Leading zeros are applied to the month, date, hour, minute, and second values if they are less than 10 using conditional assignments.

```js
const _DateString = d => {
  let dte = new Date(d);
  return `${dte.getFullYear()}${(dte.getMonth()+1 < 9)?"0"+(dte.getMonth()+1):(dte.getMonth()+1)}${(dte.getDate() < 9)?"0"+dte.getDate():dte.getDate()}${(dte.getHours() < 9)?"0"+dte.getHours():dte.getHours()}${(dte.getMinutes() < 9)?"0"+dte.getMinutes():dte.getMinutes()}${(dte.getSeconds() < 9)?"0"+dte.getSeconds():dte.getSeconds()}`;
}

console.log(_DateString(Date.now()));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, You want to convert a single digit date part into a double digit by concatenating zero(0) at the starting of that particular date part. If Yes, You can easily achieve that by finding the length of each date part and then based on ternary operator you can do the assignment.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const buildDateString = d => {
  let currentDateTime = new Date(d);
    
  //getting the date parts of today 
  var year = currentDateTime.getFullYear().toString();
  var month = (currentDateTime.getMonth() + 1).toString();
  var day =  currentDateTime.getDate().toString()
  var hours = currentDateTime.getHours().toString();
  var minutes = currentDateTime.getMinutes().toString();
  var seconds = currentDateTime.getSeconds().toString();
  
  // Just for a easily readable purpose I added each assignment in seperate line, In actual code you can put all the below statements in a single line.
  return `${year}
          ${month.length < 2 ? '0' + month : month}
          ${day.length < 2 ? '0' + day : day}
          ${hours.length < 2 ? '0' + hours : hours}
          ${minutes.length < 2 ? '0' + minutes : minutes}
          ${seconds.length < 2 ? '0' + seconds : seconds}`;
}

console.log(buildDateString(Date.now()));
```